# FOSElasticaBundle: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:

Tags: symfony, symfony4, foselasticabundle

I get the following error when populating elastic search:

```
  Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [product : {dynamic_date_formats=[], _meta={model=App\Entity\Product}, properties={name={type=text}, description={type=text}}}] [reason: Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [product : {
  dynamic_date_formats=[], _meta={model=App\Entity\Product}, properties={name={type=text}, description={type=text}}}]]
```

Basically, I followed only the documentation ( https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/doc/setup.md ) and changed `user`to `product` and the corresponding fields in my `App\Entity\Product`.

fos_elastica.yaml:

```
fos_elastica:
  clients:
    default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
  indexes:
    app:
      types:
        product:
          properties:
            name: ~
            description: ~
          persistence:
            driver: orm
            model: App\Entity\Product
            provider: ~
            finder: ~
```

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Elasticsearch version 7? I had the same problem today and think that it is related to the Elasticsearch version you are using.
If I install Elasticsearch version 6, everything is working fine.
I'm not an Elasticsearch expert, but there are probably some breaking changes in version 7 with which FOSElasticaBundle is not yet compatible.

Comment: I am using version 6 FOSElastica is not yet compatible with Elastic Search 7